# Aggregate a column element based on the time limit provided in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe, I need to find the sum of elements in the column 'data' where the rows having local time in between the local_time and the end_time.  The end_time is always local_time + 30 seconds.

Also, if the aggregated value is greater than or equal to 4 then I need to update the flags of the rows having `'local time'<=local time<='end_time'` to 1, grouping by the ID column.

Input:

```
    ID            local_time              end_time  data  Flag
0   aa  2022-01-02  10:01:06  2022-01-02  10:01:36     0     0
1   aa  2022-01-02  10:01:12  2022-01-02  10:01:42     0     0
2   aa  2022-01-02  10:01:18  2022-01-02  10:01:48     1     0
3   aa  2022-01-02  10:01:24  2022-01-02  10:01:54     1     0
4   aa  2022-01-02  10:01:30  2022-01-02  10:02:00     1     0
5   aa  2022-01-02  10:01:36  2022-01-02  10:02:06     1     0
6   aa  2022-01-02  10:01:42  2022-01-02  10:02:12     1     0
7   aa  2022-01-02  10:01:48  2022-01-02  10:02:18     0     0
8   aa  2022-01-02  10:01:54  2022-01-02  10:02:24     1     0
9   aa  2022-01-02  10:02:00  2022-01-02  10:02:30     0     0
10  aa  2022-01-02  10:02:06  2022-01-02  10:02:36     0     0
```

Output:

```
    Agg  Flag_new
0     4         1
1     5         1
2     5         1
3     5         1
4     4         1
5     3         1
6     2         1
7     1         1
8     1         1
9     0         1
10    0         0
```

Below code does the job, but it takes too much time:

```
aggr_data_sum = []
df['flag'] = 0

for i in range(len(df)):
    id = df['ID'].iloc[i]
    st_time = df['local_time'].iloc[i]
    end_time = df['end_time'].iloc[i]
    
    temp = df.loc[(df['ID'] == id) & (df['local_time'] >= st_time) & (df['local_time'] <= end_time)]
    select_indices = list(temp.index)

    aggr_sum=sum(temp['data'])
    aggr_data_sum.append(aggr_sum)
    if aggr_sum>=4:
        df.loc[select_indices,'flag']=1

df['aggr_data_sum']= aggr_data_sum

df[['aggr_data_sum','flag']]
```

Comment: I don't understand how you get this results?

Comment: Is the interval between rows always 6 seconds? Using rolling windows with variable size is not possible in pandas but if the interval is constant and there are no missing rows then there should be other solutions possible.

Comment: @SangeethaR can you recheck your expected output, I guess the expected output could be wrong

Comment: I proposed a generic solution but if the @Shaido's comment is right, you could probably use `groupby` and `rolling`.

Comment: @Shaido
yes, the interval between rows expected to be six second. But there exist the chance of  having missing records. Hence I created end_time column by adding local_time with 30 seconds.

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar, the expected output is correct only. I have included the code which gives the result. But using for loop taking more time to execute, as actual number of records in dataframe is very high.

Comment: @SangeethaR: Would a solution using a 30 second window be ok in that case (so the sum is all rows in [local_time, local_time+30s])? That is much easier than having a end_time column.

Comment: @Shaido, Yaa, that would be fine

Comment: @SangeethaR: The sample code gives 1 everywhere for the new_flag column. Could you confirm the logic here?

Comment: @Shaido... Yaa, you are right... I have updated data column and output columns. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we only need to consider the 30 seconds following each `local_time`, we can use [`pd.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with a time window of `30s`. This needs to be done on each group seperatly (as indicated by the `ID` column), so we also need an additional [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). Finally, to get the `Flag_new`, we can use a moving window again and checking the maximum `Agg` value`, if it's equal or above 4 then we set the flag to 1.

```py
def group_rolling_window(x):
    x['Agg'] = x['data'][::-1].rolling('30s', closed='both', min_periods=1).sum()[::-1].astype(int)
    x['Flag_new'] = x['Agg'].rolling('30s', closed='both', min_periods=1).max().ge(4).astype(int)
    return x

df['local_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['local_time'])
df = df.set_index('local_time').groupby('ID').apply(group_rolling_window).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
            local_time  ID              end_time  data  Flag,  Agg  Flag_new
0  2022-01-02 10:01:06  aa  2022-01-02  10:01:36     0      0    4         1
1  2022-01-02 10:01:12  aa  2022-01-02  10:01:42     0      0    5         1
2  2022-01-02 10:01:18  aa  2022-01-02  10:01:48     1      0    5         1
3  2022-01-02 10:01:24  aa  2022-01-02  10:01:54     1      0    5         1
4  2022-01-02 10:01:30  aa  2022-01-02  10:02:00     1      0    4         1
5  2022-01-02 10:01:36  aa  2022-01-02  10:02:06     1      0    3         1
6  2022-01-02 10:01:42  aa  2022-01-02  10:02:12     1      0    2         1
7  2022-01-02 10:01:48  aa  2022-01-02  10:02:18     0      0    1         1
8  2022-01-02 10:01:54  aa  2022-01-02  10:02:24     1      0    1         1
9  2022-01-02 10:02:00  aa  2022-01-02  10:02:30     0      0    0         1
10 2022-01-02 10:02:06  aa  2022-01-02  10:02:36     0      0    0         0
```

Comment: Agg column result is not as expected. I think there is a shift in 1 row while calculating Agg

Comment: @SangeethaR: Could you check your expected results again? I think my code here is correct. For example, for the last line we have a local time at 10:02:06 and end time at 10:02:36, since the data column has a 0 then the sum of all rows between these times are 0 (since it's only this row which is 0).

Comment: @SangeethaR: I think I know what happened, the data value of the last row was changed from 1 to 0 but the expected result was kept the same. The result here is be correct and I have updated the expected result in the question. (note that the code in the question gives the same result as well)

Comment: Consider the case where the data value of [0,0,0,0,0,1] for the local_time  [6,12,18,24,32,36] in seconds, then the Agg value should be [1,1,1,1,1,1] . But, the code actually giving the value as [0,1,1,1,1,1].  That's why I am saying that some shift is happening while calculating 'Agg'.

Comment: Can you please explain me which row is picked by  x['data'][::-1] ?

Comment: @SangeethaR: It does seem to work correctly. I tested with input as in your comment and the `Agg` column is all 1s. For the `x['data'][::-1]` it takes the data column and reverse it. The `[::-1]` at the end of the line reverse it back. This is necessary to get correct results when using the moving window (since it needs to consider future rows and not past rows).

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

You can use `merge` and `query` to filter out rows according your condition then `groupby_sum` to aggregate data. Finally use `join` (or `concat`) to concatenate dataframes:

```
offset = pd.Timedelta(seconds=30)
filter_local_time = lambda x: x['local_time_y'].between(x['local_time_x'], x['local_time_x'] + offset)

df1 = df1.join(df1[['ID', 'local_time']].reset_index().merge(df1, on='ID')
                  .loc[filter_local_time].groupby('index')['data'].sum().to_frame('Agg')
                  .assign(Flag_new=lambda x: x['Agg'].ge(4).astype(int)))
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
    ID          local_time  data  Agg  Flag_new
0   aa 2022-01-02 10:01:06     0    4         1
1   aa 2022-01-02 10:01:12     0    5         1
2   aa 2022-01-02 10:01:18     1    5         1
3   aa 2022-01-02 10:01:24     1    5         1
4   aa 2022-01-02 10:01:30     1    4         1
5   aa 2022-01-02 10:01:36     1    4         1
6   aa 2022-01-02 10:01:42     1    3         0
7   aa 2022-01-02 10:01:48     0    2         0
8   aa 2022-01-02 10:01:54     1    2         0
9   aa 2022-01-02 10:02:00     0    1         0
10  aa 2022-01-02 10:02:06     1    1         0
```

**Note**: for the input dataframe, I only keep `ID`, `local_time` and `data` columns.

Comment: Hi @Corralien can you check once I think yours Agg column and OP's Agg column does not match

Comment: @SangeethaR. I updated my solution can you check it please?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar. You're right. The question was not clear for me. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Corralien, Agg column is fine. If Agg>=4, then for that ID, rows within next 30seconds has to be updated to 1 in flag_new.